# ORA-01858: Error when trying to insert into timestamp(0) column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have data in below mentioned format, when I am trying to insert into table I am getting errors

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

How can I successfully insert record into table?

```
create table mytab (dt timestamp(0));

Insert into mytab
   (dt)
 Values
   (TO_TIMESTAMP('16/JUL/13 2:53:08. PM','DD/MON/YY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify zero fractional seconds.  Here's your error:

```
SQL> create table mytab (dt timestamp(0));

Table created.

SQL> Insert into mytab
   (dt)
 Values
   (TO_TIMESTAMP('16/JUL/13 2:53:08. PM','DD/MON/YY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM'));   2    3    4  
   (TO_TIMESTAMP('16/JUL/13 2:53:08. PM','DD/MON/YY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM'))
                 *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

SQL>
```

Let's fix the input

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  Insert into mytab
  2     (dt)
  3   Values
  4*    (TO_TIMESTAMP('16/JUL/13 2:53:08.00 PM','DD/MON/YY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM'))
SQL> r
  1  Insert into mytab
  2     (dt)
  3   Values
  4*    (TO_TIMESTAMP('16/JUL/13 2:53:08.00 PM','DD/MON/YY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM'))

1 row created.

SQL>
```

So even though you've specified a timestamp with a zero precision, your input still needs to match the mask.  Which means you need to have `.00` to match the `.FF` .

Alternatively, don't bother including the fractional seconds at all:

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  insert into mytab
  2     (dt)
  3   Values
  4*    (TO_TIMESTAMP('16/JUL/13 2:53:08 PM','DD/MON/YY fmHH12fm:MI:SS AM'))
SQL> r
  1  insert into mytab
  2     (dt)
  3   Values
  4*    (TO_TIMESTAMP('16/JUL/13 2:53:08 PM','DD/MON/YY fmHH12fm:MI:SS AM'))

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

Incidentally, note that a TIMESTAMP(0) will round any fractional seconds, rounding up at the half second.  Whether that matters depends on how you'll be populating the column and how accurate the time needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

You need the second fraction:

```
Insert into mytab(dt)
 Values
    (TO_TIMESTAMP('16/JUL/13 2:53:08.00 PM','DD/MON/YY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one "." after minutes

this works

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP('16/JUL/13 2:53:08 PM','DD/MON/YY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM') 
from dual
```

Comment: I agree this works, but I'm always happier when the input string balances the mask.

Comment: @APC yes it is better